# Inner class property make read only to all accessing classes except outer class

Tags: c#, inner-classes, readonly

I am new to C# and while coding I stumbled on this. I'm unsure how to word it, so I'll share the code first (it is dummy code just to explain my question).

```
public class DatabaseConnector
{
   public Caching Cache { get; set; }
   //More properties
   //some methods
   public DatabaseConnector(string[] parameters)
   {
      Connect(parameters);
   }
   protected void Connect(string[] parameters) 
   {
         Cache = new Caching();
         Cache.Enabled = true; //this value is set depending on parameters and the database condition.
         //Irrelevant Code 
   }
    
   //Method to get the database
   
   public class Caching
   {
      public bool Enabled { get; set; }
      //other properties
      public Caching()
      {
          this.Enabled = false;
          //other properties 
      }
   }
}
```

Now When user uses the class as

```
DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(arguments);
 
dbConnector.Cache.Enabled = false; //Should throw error     

if(dbConnector.Cache.Enabled) //should work.
    dbConnector.Executesomemethod();
else
   dbConnector.ExecutesomeOthermethod();
```

I want to make the inner class `Caching` `Enabled` property as the read only to the all classes except the `Outer class`. Currently what I am doing is in each `Executesomemethod(), ExecutesomeOthermethod(),....,n` I am checking the conditions which are already checked in the constructor/connect method to set the `Enabled` value.

What I want is a way to make the `inner class` property read only to all accessing classes except the `Outer class`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want every class that inherits Caching class won't be able to set Enabled properties except DatabaseConnector class?

Comment: I suspect you don't want the `Cache` property itself to be writable by clients, do you?

Comment: Also, do you need the `DatabaseConnector` to be able to change the value of `Enabled` itself *after* construction? If not, Neill's answer is perfect. If you do, it won't help.

Comment: @JonSkeet No there are some proerties from that class like`TimeOut` and other things like how long the cache should hold  that should be writable.

Comment: @JonSkeet currently I am not changing anywhere other that constructor but there is possibility of that is happening. That's why need another  approach towards that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way of doing that - other than the visibility of the class itself, outer classes have no extra access to the members within a nested class.

Two options:

- Keep a `cachingEnabled` private field within `DatabaseConnector` instead, and give `Cache` an instance of the `DatabaseConnector` to fetch it from. (It can read private fields, as it's a nested class.)
- Separate the read-only part from the writable part:

  ```
  public interface ICache
  {
      bool Enabled { get; }
  }

  public class DatabaseConnector
  {
      private Cache cache;
      public ICache Cache { get { return cache; } }

      ...

      private class Cache
      {
          // Implementation with writable property
          public bool Enabled { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```

Note that because the implementation is a *private* nested class, callers can't even cast the result of the `Cache` property and call the setter that way. (They could use reflection, in a full-trust environment, of course.)

Comment: That is only true if there is no requirement to re-use the Cache class outside the DatabaseConnector class.

Answer (score 2):

Change the property:

```
public bool Enabled { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public bool Enabled { get; private set; }
```

Change the Cache class constructor to:

```
public Cache(bool enabled)
{
   Enabled = enabled;
}
```

Change when constructing Cache class to:

```
Cache = new Caching(true);
// remove this line Cache.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this suit your purpose:

```
public class DatabaseConnector
{
    public Caching Cache { get; set; }

    public DatabaseConnector(string[] paramters)
    {
        Connect(paramters);
    }

    protected void Connect(string[] paramters)
    {
        ICaching Cache = new Caching();
        Cache.Enabled = true;
    }

    private interface ICaching
    {
        bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }

    public class Caching : ICaching
    {
        private bool _enabled { get; set; }

        public Caching()
        {
            _enabled = false;
        }

        bool ICaching.Enabled
        {
            get { return _enabled; }
            set { _enabled = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

So the private interface will expose the properties to the outer class but anything outside this class won't be able to see the Enabled property.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `ICaching` to have a readonly property? (This can be slightly more simply achieved, too...)

Comment: +1 I think I will go with @JonSkeet first approach as I have only one proerty to handle. But seems like I need to read lot about abstraction. But good thinking there.

Comment: I would also go with the @JonSkeet approach!